# Equivalence relation over groups $a\asymp_sb :\rightarrow\exists n\in\Bbb Z:as^n=b$: terminology and decision problem

Tags: group-theory, terminology, big-list, equivalence-relations

Let's define this relation over the elements of an **infinite** group $(G,\cdot,e)$

$$a\asymp_sb :\rightarrow\exists n\in\Bbb Z(as^n=b)$$

where $a^n$ is defined as follow

1)$a^0=e$

2)$a^{n+1}=aa^n$

> ***Qestion 1, is it an equivalence relation?Is my proof correct for all the groups?***

**1-** it is reflexive

> $a\asymp_sa$ because $as^0=ae=a$

**2-** it is symmetric

> If $a\asymp_sb$ then $b\asymp_sa$ because if $as^n=b$ then $a=b(s^n)^{-1}=bs^{-n}$

**3-** it is transitive

> If $a\asymp_sb$ and $b\asymp_sc$ then $a\asymp_sc$ because if $as^n=b$ and $bs^m=c$ then $as^ns^m=as^{n+m}=c$

---

> ***Qestion 2, does $G / \asymp_s$ has a name? What are some basic results about it?***

Is very interesting to see that if we take  $(\Bbb Z,+,0)$ then

$\Bbb Z /\asymp_ 0$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z $ because $a\asymp_0b$ implies $a=b$

$\asymp_ 1$ induces only one Equivalence class because $m\asymp_ 1 n$ for every pair of $m$ and $n$

$\asymp_ 2$ creates two Equivalence classes, the odd numbers and the even ones..

In my opinion is interesting to ask if in a group $G$ exist an element $1_G$ such that $\asymp_ {1_G}$ induces only one equivalence class on $G$ or in other words if every element of $G$ is is the form $b=z1_G^n$ for a fixed $z$.

Another queston could be tha following: when for group $G$ exist an element $u$ such that  $|G / \asymp_u|$ is finite? In that case every element of $G$ can be written in the form $a=z_iu^n$ for some elements $z_1,z_2,...,z_{|G / \asymp_u|}$ and $\neg(z_i \asymp_u z_j)$

---

> ***Qestion 3, Is there an easy and fast way to know if two elements are equivalent via $\asymp_s$***

This problem looks, at first, like the conjugacy problem for groups. In fact its structure is similar to the conjugacy problem.

> $\asymp_s$ **-Problem** - given $s\in G$, $a\in G$ and $b\in G$ do
>   exists an $n\in \Bbb Z$ such that $$as^n= b$$?
>
> **Conjugacy problem** - given $a\in G$ and $b\in G$ do exists an $\gamma\in G$ such that $$a\gamma=\gamma b$$?

The "$\asymp_s$ **-Problem**" is like asking if $log_s(a^{-1}b)$ has a solution. Because if $log_s(a^{-1}b)$ exists then $a\asymp_s b$:

$$as^{log_s(a^{-1}b)}=b$$

Where the map the map $log_s:\langle s\rangle\rightarrow \Bbb Z$ is the inverse map of the group power defined above $s^{-}:\Bbb Z \rightarrow G$.

Is this problem as hard as the conjugation problem? Is it related to the conjuagation in some way?

---

Comment: Yes your proof is correct. The equivalence classes are exactly the left cosets in $G$ of the cyclic subgroup $\langle s \rangle$ generated by $s$.

Comment: Hi Derek, thank you for the of terminology, thanks to this I was able to learn more... but is useless to say that the amount of informations (results and theormes) about Cyclic subgrps and Cosets is... is a bit overwhelming. It's too generic to help me about the more "precise sides" of my question. PS:I have added a third question (I forgot to add it when I posted the question).

Comment: @DerekHolt , I've opened a bounty. If you want you can put your comment as an answer, and add some info about question 3.